# How to reset form body in bootstrap modal box without losing value?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for my bad english. I have a modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="col-4 col-form-label text-end">Radiobox:</label>
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="radiobox" id="checkRadiobox" value="1">
                </div>
```

When i using this script code:

```
 $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
        $(this).find("input,textarea,select").val("").end()
            .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]").prop("checked", false).end();
    });
```

To reset modal after close.

It is work fine to input text but radiobox is losing value. Modal is turning into:

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="col-4 col-form-label text-end">Radiobox:</label>
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="radiobox" id="checkRadiobox" value>
                </div>
```

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is because the `prop("checked", "")` method sets the checked property to an empty string, which removes the checked attribute from the radio button element. To set the radio button back to its original unselected state, you should use the `prop("checked", false)` method instead:

```
$("#exampleModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
 $(this).find("input,textarea,select").val("").end()
        .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]").prop("checked", false).end();
});
```

This will set the checked property to false, which will deselect the radio button when the modal is closed.

Comment: It's still losing value sir.